# garbage collector and double allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, garbage-collection

my question is will garbage collector will free a memory if the variable allocated is malloced again without freeing the memory.

eg:

```
ptr1 = malloc(100)
ptr1 = malloc(200)
```

In this case will the first allocated memory will be deallocated by garbage collector??
If yes then when..???

Comment: Sorry, but which language are you confused with? The lack of semicolons suggests Javascript, can that be right?

Comment: +1 to compensate the silly anonymous downvote.Ignorance is not a crime & if it was SO wouldn't exist.

Comment: while C doesn't provide garbage collection, that's exactly its function. When ptr1 is overwritten, the memory block originally pointed by ptr1 is marked 'free for collection'.

Comment: In case this malloc was done in a language which supports garbage collection will the first allocated memory will be cleared..?

Comment: @MrLister, what do you mean but 'it isn't'? Even a naive implementation of 'reference counting' will deal with this situation... Please, let me know.

Comment: C doesn't have a naive implementation of reference counting. If you want to, you can write your own alternative to `malloc`, but nothing like that is built in to the standard libraries.

Comment: @MrLister, that's why my comment starts with 'while C doesn't provide garbage collection'... my comment my seem ambiguous... I meant that it's "garbage collection's function"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will result in a memory leak.

There is no garbage collector in C.
You have to do the memory management yourself.

```
ptr1 = malloc(100);
free(ptr1);
ptr1 = malloc(200);
...
...
free(ptr1);
```

Comment: Consider if garbage collector exists then will it free the memory..?

Comment: @goutham: The Q is hypothetical ofcourse So is the answer, If the garbage collector is any good then yes it will.You might want to have a look at [Boehm garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) if you are interested in those.

Answer (score 1):

There is no garbage collector in C.

Answer (score 1):

C does not *have* a garbage collector;  the code you've shown will lead to a memory leak.

You're responsible for deallocating memory with `free()`:

```
ptr1 = malloc(100);
free(ptr1);
ptr1 = malloc(200);
```